# php - save part of an unknown string in a variable

Tags: php, string, variables, split

can anyone help me please. In a loop, I get a list with page titles from an external website. And these titles are unknown strings. Every Page title has a name and a ID like "NAME X - PRJ12345".

the title are saved in `$title_mainpage`

And I want to save the String Part "NAME X" in variable `$title_name` and the unknown ID of the String in variable `$title_id`.

Every title are different, but the ID has always the same length - start with "PRJ" + 5 numbers.

I hope the question is clear. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `list` and explode functions. `list` actually assign variables to the values as they were in arrays. While `explode` break the string into array. With the help of `list` you don't need to use `arrays` explicitly.

```
$variable = "NAME X-PRJ12345";
list($title_name, $title_id) = explode('-', $variable);
echo $title_name . "<br>";
echo $title_id;
```

Possible output will be like this:

```
NAME X 
PRJ12345
```

For deep information you can see documentation for [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: I am glad, I am of your help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$x='NAME X - PRJ12345';
$arr=explode('-',$x);
$title_name=echo $arr[0];
$title_id=echo $arr[1];
```